# Pie chart of single column in R Language

Tags: r, pie-chart

How can I create a pie chart of a single column in R language?
Tried searching on google for it but I cant find any thing related to a single column.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your data frame looks like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(single_column = c(21, 48, 15, 16))

df
#>   single_column
#> 1            21
#> 2            48
#> 3            15
#> 4            16
```

Then you can do:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = 1, y = single_column, fill = factor(single_column))) + 
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), 
            aes(label = single_column)) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This comes from Quick-R's website:

```
# Pie Chart with Percentages
slices <- c(10, 12, 4, 16, 8)
lbls <- c("US", "UK", "Australia", "Germany", "France")
pct <- round(slices/sum(slices)*100)
lbls <- paste(lbls, pct) # add percents to labels
lbls <- paste(lbls,"%",sep="") # ad % to labels
pie(slices,labels = lbls, col=rainbow(length(lbls)),
   main="Pie Chart of Countries")
```

Hope it works for your needs.